# C Returning an array from a function

Tags: c, arrays

And having some trouble grasping arrays in C and how to return them via a function. If I do something like this

```
int main()
{
     int num_set[10]={0,1}; //initialize first two elements as 0,1 and rest as 0
     int* p=num_set;             //assign array to int pointer called p
     printf("\n%i",&num_set);    //outputs 2686660 on my machine
     printf("\n%i",&num_set[0]); //also outputs 2686660
     printf("\n%i",p);           //also outputs 2686660
     printf("\n%i",p[1]);*       //outputs 0; the same as num_set[1]
 }
```

It works as expected, but when I try to return an array through another function like the following

```
int multiply_by_2(int given_number)
{
     int num_set[10];
     for(int fun_counter=0; fun_counter<10; fun_counter++)
     {
          num_set[fun_counter] = (given_number*2) ;
     }
     return num_set;  //return int array num_set to caller
}

int main()
{
     int* p = multiply_by_2(300)    //assign array returned by function to p
     for(int main_counter=0; main_counter>10; main_counter++)
     {
          printf("\np[%i] = %i"
                 , i, p[i]);
     }
}
```

I get an error saying "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'"

They was no error when I assigned the array to an int pointer in the first code, but I get this error when I try to return it through a function.

Please help.

Comment: You've declared `multiply_by_2` to return an `int`, but you're trying to return an `int[10]`.

Comment: @Andro47 Now why wouldn't that compile?

Comment: You can't return arrays in C.

Comment: As for your question, Oli explained it why it won't compile, but I REALLY don't get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of errors here.

1. The return type of the function `multiply_by_2` needs to be `int*` - i.e a pointer to an integer. What is actually returned is a pointer to the first element of the array.
2. You are attempting to return a variable initialized on the stack (`num_set`). This will 
   disappear as soon as the `multiply_by_two` function exits, because it is an [automatic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable).  Instead, you should use the `malloc` function to allocate heap memory. Here's a link explaining the difference between [stack and heap memory](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)
3. You have a `>` where you should have a `<` in the `for` loop in `main`. As written the loop will immediately exit.
4. Minor point - the number 10 is repeated several times throughout the code. It is better practice to use a variable or a `#define` to give the number a meaningful name

Here's an amended version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //This is required to use malloc

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int* multiply_by_2(int given_number)
{
    int *num_set =malloc(sizeof(int)*ARRAY_SIZE);
    for(int fun_counter=0; fun_counter<ARRAY_SIZE; fun_counter++)
    {
        num_set[fun_counter] = (given_number*2) ;
    }
    return num_set;  //return int array num_set to caller
}

int main()
{
    int* p = multiply_by_2(300);    //assign array returned by function to p
    for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
         printf("\np[%i] = %i", i, p[i]);
    }
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: Its really interesting to know about how variable gets stored in the memory and the malloc syntax. Am a bit confused of why I can return variable like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/28181def7d7f527ff2d9). Shouldn't variable t get cleared after random_function exits ?

Answer (score 3):

In C you cannot return array by value. You would have to return the pointer of the array you want to return.

Pass a pointer and a size for a buffer to store your results.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong on so many levels, but the compiler error comes from your declaration of "multiply_by_2". You declare it to return an integer, but then you try to return a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try something like this:

```
int* multiply_by_2(int size, int given_number)
{
     int *ip = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int)); // dynamically create int x[size]
     for(int fun_counter=0; fun_counter < size; fun_counter++)
     {
          ip[fun_counter] = (given_number*2) ;
     }
     return ip;  //return int array num_set to caller
}
```

Caller must `free()` returned memory.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int *ip = multiply_by_2(3, 2);
    // ip points to array {4, 4, 4}
    free(ip);
    return 0;
}
```

We say that the function caller becomes owner of returned memory, that's why you are responsible to call `free()` later.

Answer (score 1):

```
int multiply_by_2(int given_number) // not returning an array, but just an int
```

The return type of your function is `int` therefore you will get an error when trying to assign it to `int *`. Change it to the following:

```
int* multiply_by_2(int given_number)
```

This change is acceptable because in C, an array of `int`s is interchangeable with a pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your header is wrong. Should be
`int* multiply_by_2(int given_number)`
You need to return **pointer** of int, not just int.

Another thing, in the function `multiply_by_2` you have created local array. That means that the array will be deleted after the function will end.
You must use dynamic allocation (malloc and free).

Answer (score 1):

Three major problems in your program:

> - The return type of function is `int` but you are returning an `int *` type.
> - You are returning the pointer to an automatic local variable.
> - Second expression in `for` loop in `main` would not let the body of loop to execute.

Change return type of the function to `int *` and use dynamic allocation.

```
int* multiply_by_2(int given_number)
{
     int* num_set = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
     // rest of you code
}
```

And finally change second expression in your `for` loop in `main` to `main_counter < 10`. Use `free` in `main` to free the allocated memory.